# Node.js AES-256-CBC encryption issue

Tags: php, node.js, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to create an encrypted string according to one sample code which is given in PHP, my main problem is Node.js `crypto` module doesn't accept keys with more than 32 bytes length but PHP `openssl_encrypt` does, it seems that's why I'm getting `Invalid key size error`.

here is my js code:

```
    let iv = sha1(await HelpersService.makeRandomNumber(null, null, 16));
    iv = iv.substr(0, 16);
    const text = bundledData;
    const password = sha1(this.credentials.appSecret);
    let salt = sha1(await HelpersService.makeRandomNumber(null, null, 4));
    salt = salt.substr(0, 4);
    const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password + salt).digest('hex');
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let encoded = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encoded += cipher.final('hex');
```

and this is the PHP sample:

```
   function generateCashOutAPIHashKey($app_secret ){
      //remove plus(+) sign from gsm number.
      $data = 'text';
      $iv = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 16);
      $password = sha1($app_secret);
      $salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 4);
      $saltWithPassword = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
      $encrypted = openssl_encrypt("$data", 'aes-256-cbc', "$saltWithPassword", null, $iv    );
      return $encrypted;
    }
```

Comment: _Small Probably Irrelevant point_ You dont need to place variables in quotes when passing as parameters like `openssl_encrypt("$data",` a simple `openssl_encrypt($data,` will suffice

Comment: PHP implicitly truncates the key length according to the specified algorithm, i.e. to 32 bytes for AES-256. The _crypto_ module of NodeJS code does not do this automatically, so the key must be explicitly truncated with `substr(0, 32)`. Also, the PHP code returns the ciphertext Base64 encoded, i.e. in the NodeJS code the output encoding must be changed in the `update()` and `final()` call from `'hex'` to `'base64'`.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much! its alright now. can you post it please I will mark it as an answer

Comment: You're welcome. I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key generated in the PHP and NodeJS code has a length of 64 bytes. The used encryption AES-256 needs a 32 bytes key. In the PHP code, [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) *implicitly* shortens the 64 bytes key to 32 bytes. In the NodeJS code this has to be done *explicitly*:

```
const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password + salt).digest('hex').substr(0, 32);
```

Also, `openssl_encrypt()` returns the ciphertext Base64 encoded by default. In the NodeJS code the result is returned hex encoded. Here you have to change the output encoding from `'hex'` to `'base64'` in the `update()` and `final()` call:

```
let encoded = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');  
encoded += cipher.final('base64');
```

Please note that the PHP reference code has a number of vulnerabilities:

- [`mt_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) is not a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (CSPRNG). PHP provides cryptographically secure methods for deriving a random IV / salt, e.g. [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.csprng.php) or [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.csprng.php).
- The key is inferred using SHA-256. It is more secure to use a reliable key derivation function such as [PBKDF2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php). A 4 bytes [salt](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27971) is generally too small.
- [SHA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48291) is considered insecure in most contexts and must no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone have a problem with the following ?

> crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password +
> salt).digest('hex').substr(0, 32);

I understand the intent of needing a 32 byte value produced by sha256 but if you hex encode and then take the first 32 characters of the string you have SIGNIFICANTLY reduced the value of this.  You now have a string 32 characters long that has only 16 possible values (0-9a-f) for each character.  You really want a 32 byte value that has 256 possible values for each byte.  You have changed your key security of your encryption key from the intended 256^32 (1.1E77) to 16^32 (3.4E38).

> crypto.createHash('sha256').update('').digest('hex');
> 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'
> crypto.createHash('sha256').update('').digest('hex').substr(0,32);
> 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb924'

Find a way to use the byte values produced by SHA256.

Comment: @Gray thank you very much, actually I got your point but I am just a consumer of third-party service and it's their intention to create the keys like this, I'm just simulating the code but if I wanna make the same encryption in the future for sure I will consider your point.